# How to navigate one page to another in Angular Js

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi i am very new for AngularJs and i am trying to make page navigation with the help of Angular Routing concept and for this i searched lot in google but i could not find solution to my requirement

I need Login page with Angular tags and how to navigate from one page to another as like my structure

`case1:--`When login Success its navigate to Home page from login page
`case2:--`When login Failure its navigate to Failure page from login page
`case3:-`When tapped on Register button need to direct Register-page same like Forgot-password also

### app.js:

```
  'use strict';
    //Define Routing for app
    angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController'
          })
        .when('/forgotPassword', {
            templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
            controller: 'forgotController'
          })
       .when('/home', {
           templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
           controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/login'
        });

    }]);
});
```

Comment: so what's not working here?  This looks like pretty standard [tag:AngularJs] (not [tag:angular]) routing code.....

Comment: That doesn't even make sense.  What does "I want login page with angular tags" even mean?  When you go to `yoursite.com/login`, does it not show the login page?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is incredibly old, but no answer and ranked #2 in search on StackOverflow.com, "angularjs how to navigate with route"

Using angularjs 1.7.8, https://plnkr.co/edit/3bSYIp5Lzsf34ejh91xs?p=preview

The basics of what you are looking for

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/about", {
      templateUrl: "about.html",
      controller: "aboutController"
    })
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "mainController.html",
      controller: "mainController"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
});

angular.module("app").controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.goToAbout = function() {
      $location.path("about");
  }
}]);

angular.module("app").controller('aboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log("main controller loaded");
}]);
```

Even in early 2020, my company uses angularjs. This is really here for the future me when I jump back and forth between Angular 2....n and AngularJS.